# Want to add lights to existing outlets - beginning of circuit or end?

Tags: lighting, receptacle, remodeling

thanks in advance for help

Question is this.  I have romex running from the panel to a set of 6 outlets.  If I want to add lights and a switch, can I simply add them FROM the first outlet?  Details below..

Now my girlfriend decides she wants a set of three small lights in front of where the tv will go for a nice ambiance.   My question is this - The FIRST outlet in the circuit is down near the right wall by the tv and then they daisy chain around half of the room.  I want to add a switch and three small lights.  Can I add a third set of wires(romex) running from the FIRST outlet in the circuit to the switch I will put in and then to the three small lights above? Or do I have to do it from the last outlet?  My thought was, I could simply add a third romex cable to the first outlet(two there already, one for power in, and one that daisys to the next outlet)....and connect the first outlet to the switch, and then the switch to the first light, then to the second, then to the third... etc....

Comment: You could tap into any of the outlets, run new Romex up to a switch then break the hot at the switch and take the Romex up to the new light boxes. With the switch off the lights will be off switch on lights on. Make sure to turn the breaker off when doing the wiring.

Comment: Ed Beal.  Accurate answer, move it from comments to the answer section.

Comment: Thank you..what I thought but also tried to tap into the second switch of a threeway switch and that didn't work well lol

Comment: @TimSeedorf Three-way switches are a different beast as you may not have an unswitched hot and neutral there. An unswitched outlet always has both.

Comment: hehe.. yes, I diagrammed it out and realized that, my plugged in light was acting as another switch and that only at a few times was it ever going to be able to have a power flow....  I realized, I would need to go tap into the FIRST light switch so it could have constant power.... but I decided not to anyways